# Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. on glassfish for remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, glassfish

I checked the solution for this problem in `stackoverflow` and in other sites but I couldn't find any solution.
My problem is when I try to debug by placing `breakpoints` I am getting the below error saying.

> Message: “Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection Refused”

**In GlassFish**

`jvm settings`

`Debug: enabled` (I enabled this option)

`Debug Options: 
-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9001`

in

> domain.xml

`-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9001`

I changed the default address `9009` to `9001` because `9009` is not working,
and we have one `glassfish` have multiple `domains` to overcome conflicts for `debug default address` I changed the address for debug

**Eclipse IDE** in **debug configuration**

`in Connect`

Host: `localhost`

port: `9001`

Allow termination of remote VM (I enabled this options)

`in Source`

I added all my project files

`in common`

I enabled `debug`

as of now for me everything is looking fine but still I am unable to debug the code, can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this problem it's always been a blocked port. Either the server's firewall or some other firewall between you and that server. Make sure the debug port, 9001 or whatever you're configured for, is open.